# asp.net user control with multiple content area

Tags: asp.net, web, webforms, user-controls

In this website and some other websites there are topics about creating an asp.net user control which has a content placeholder or content area so you can put whatever you like inside your own user control. It will be like this :

```
<someprefix:yourcontrolname runat="server"> 
   <content>
   //plain text or complicated control can be here
   </content>
</someprefix:yourcontrolname>
```

But how can I create one with multiple content area like this one :

```
<someprefix:yourcontrolname runat="server"> 
   <content1>
   //plain text or complicated control can be here
   </content1>
   <content2>
   //plain text or complicated control can be here
   </content2>
</someprefix:yourcontrolname>
```

Comment: Something like this is what you need to setup: http://forums.asp.net/t/1818461.aspx?Allow+usercontrol+property+to+be+set+using+nested+child+element

Comment: @BrianMains it doesn't work. content I put between <text> </text> won't be displayed and I can't wrap it through a div (I can't work with it in UI code)